# Default low row height of table and tabular environments

Tags: tables, tabularx, xtable

Suppose that we have this code:

```
\begin{table}
\caption{xxxx.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{Gray}
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/BBBCCCCCCCC \\
  \hline
  2 & SDSDSDSDSD/FDFDFDFDF \\
  \hline
    2 & gGGGGGGGGG/TTTTTTTTTT \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{Gray}
\end{tabular}
\label{table:QQ}
\end{table}
```

The output of this table is:

[image]

As you can see the height of table rows is not fix with font size (+texts are not in center of every cell/we have tendency to upward) . Why we have this behavior in default table appearance? How can i have a table with better appearance?

Comment: See [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31672/5764) (possible duplicate).

Comment: your image shows why the baseline in each row is where it is, essentially it is positioned so the latin letters fit from the top of an A to the bottom of a g if you write all uppercase with no descenders that gives the appearance of more space underneath.

Comment: Increasing \arraystretch adds more to the top than the bottom, so 1.5 is just about right.

Comment: the table rows _are_ all the same height in your image (and will be unless you put in over-large content, just as lines of a paragraph are evenly spaced unless you add something unexpended large.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cellspace` package, which lets you define a *minimal* vertical spacing between a row and the above and below rows. Additionnally, I loaded the `caption` package to ensure a correct vertical spacing between caption and table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{xxxx.}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|Sc|Sc|}
  \hline
  \rowcolor{Gray}
  % after \\: \hline or \cline{col1-col2} \cline{col3-col4} ...
  1 & AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/BBBCCCCCCCC \\
  \hline
  2 & SDSDSDSDSD/FDFDFDFDF \\
  \hline
    2 & gGGGGGGGGG/TTTTTTTTTT \\
  \hline
  \rowcolor{Gray}
\end{tabular}
\label{table:QQ}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]